# JavaScript click not working with InnerHtml

Tags: javascript

When user click on tag with class ".btn" it should console.log(1), if user click on "Next" button - .buttons>button should replace with given values in array tasks. It works well with replacement, but after replacement click ".btn" doen't work anymore.

What issue?

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn">
        <span class="text1">var 1</span>
    </button>
    <button class="btn">
        <span class="text2">var 2</span>
    </button>
</div>

<button class="right">
    <span class="text">Next</span>
</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".btn").on('click', function() {
        console.log(1)
    })
</script>


<script>
    var tasks = [
        ["task1", "task_addition1", "1", "var1", "img1.url", "var1", "img1.url"],
        ["task2", "task_addition2", "2", "var2", "img1.url", "var2", "img2.url"],
        ["task3", "task_addition3", "1", "var3", "img1.url", "var3", "img3.url"],
    ];
    var task_number = 0;

    $(".right").on('click', function() {

        let buttons = ""
        for (var i = 3; i < tasks[task_number].length;) {
            buttons += '<button class="btn btn-light"><span class="text1">{}</span></button>'.replace("{}", tasks[task_number][i])
            i += 2;
        };
        $(".buttons").html(buttons);

        task_number += 1
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binded event will be removed when you replace buttons. In this case, you should bind an event to parent(I usually use `body` selector) and provide selector to find it's children.

```js
var tasks = [
        ["task1", "task_addition1", "1", "var1", "img1.url", "var1", "img1.url"],
        ["task2", "task_addition2", "2", "var2", "img1.url", "var2", "img2.url"],
        ["task3", "task_addition3", "1", "var3", "img1.url", "var3", "img3.url"],
    ];
var task_number = 0;

$(".right").on('click', function() {
  let buttons = ""
  for (var i = 3; i < tasks[task_number].length;) {
    buttons += '<button class="btn btn-light"><span class="text1">{}</span></button>'.replace("{}", tasks[task_number][i])
    i += 2;
  };
  $(".buttons").html(buttons);

  task_number += 1
})
    
$("body").on("click", ".btn", function() {
  console.log(1)
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="btn">
            <span class="text1">var 1</span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn">
            <span class="text2">var 2</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <button class="right">
        <span class="text">Next</span>
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```